# How do I delete all characters starting from a specific text on a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

The best way to explain this is by example. I'm using jQuery to do this.

Example I have a string

```
var str = "1.) Ben"
```

how can I **dynamically** omit the character `1.)` including the space such that `str === "Ben"`

`str` can be dynamic such that order can increment from ones, tens, to hundreds.

E.G.

```
var str = "52.) Ken Bush"
```

or

```
var str = "182.) Hailey Quen"
```

Expected output

```
str === "Ken Bush"
```

or

```
str === "Hailey Quen"
```

Comment: You can split the string by ') ' which will return array, and then trim the second part of array to remove any spaces if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex replacement to get what you want.

```
var str = "182.) Hailey"

var newStr = str.replace(/^\d+\.\)\s*/, '')
// Hailey

var s = "1456.) Hard Spocker".replace(/^\d+\.\)\s*/, '')
// Hard Spocker
```

> `^` makes sure that the pattern is matched at the start of the string only
>
> `\d+` will match one or more digits.
>
> `\.` will match the `.` with escaping
>
> `)` is a symbol so we need to escape it using `\` as `\)`
>
> `\s*` will match one or more spaces.

You can learn about these symbols [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: I added the example with spaces.

Comment: thanks. can you please explain what ` /\d+.\)\s*/` meant?

Comment: You might want a `^` at the start (after the initial `/`) so that it only ever replaces the pattern at the start of the string. Otherwise, `"Hello (12.) World"` would become `"Hello (World"`.

Comment: @Zastai Thanks I updated the answer. I did think about this earlier but I assumed that the strings will always start with this pattern and hence the code will only replace the first occurrence. But I agree this will make it generic.

Answer (score 4):

Example

```
var str = "182.) Hailey Quen"
    var test = str.split(') ');
    test = test[1];
    //output "Hailey Quen"
```

Comment: what if a string is like `182.)      Test`?

Comment: or if the string is like `"182.) Hailey Quen () test"`

Comment: This is another question, I guess you want to find specific name then instead of remove items before specific characters. Use indexOf and subString for that

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.substring()` and `.indexOf()` as shown :-

```
var str = "182.) Hailey Quen"
alert(str.substring(str.indexOf(' ')))
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/je7ep8xm/)

OR use `.split()` as shown :-

```
var str = "182.) Hailey Quen"
alert($.trim(str.split(')')[1]))
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/je7ep8xm/2/)

Comment: `.pop()` is generally safer than `[1]` on a `.split()` result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it regular expression,

```
var str = "52.) Ken".replace(/\d+\.\)\s/g,"");
console.log(str); //Ken
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k8j2wgsy/)

If you have zero or more than zero spaces after the `)` symbol then you can use `*`,

```
var str = "52.) Ken".replace(/\d+\.\)\s*/g,"");
console.log(str); //Ken
```

Dismantling regex used,

1. `/` states regex left border
2. `\d` **d** states normal character d, if we want to make it match
   numbers then we have to escape it with `\`
3. `+` It states that one or more number should be there.
4. `\.` Again **.** is a metacharacter to match any valid character, so
   escape it.
5. `\)` Parenthesis is also a metacharacter to close a group, escape
   it.
6. `\s*` 12.) can be followed by zero or more spaces.
7. `/` states regex right boundary.
8. `g` global flag, which used to do a search recursively.

Comment: @HardSpocker This regex will work for that string also. https://jsfiddle.net/k8j2wgsy/1/

Comment: how about something like `A2: Hailey Quen`

Comment: @HardSpocker https://jsfiddle.net/k8j2wgsy/2/ For that you need to add an or condition in regex. `.replace(/\d+(\.\)|\:)\s/g,"")`

Comment: ive done something like this `.replace(/\w\d+\:\s*/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var testURL = "182.) Hailey Quen";
var output = testURL.substring(testURL.lastIndexOf(")") + 1).trim();
console.log(output);
```

*trim function will help to remove extra space if any.Hope it will help